# Mysql to array not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey Everyone i got a little problem! I know its something simple but for some reason i can not figure it out (arrays are kicking my butt!)

I want the results to display like the following...

```
title 1 | title 2 | title 3 | title 4 |
Title 5 | title 6 | title 7 | title 8 |
```

But for some reason when the code runs it shows as the following...

```
t | i |
```

It spells out the title 1 and not the whole word for each cell of the table. 
What am i doing wrong?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT title FROM donuts"); 
$rows = 2; 
$cols = ceil(count($result)/$rows); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
echo $result=$row['title']; 
echo "<table border='1'>"; 
$i=0; 
for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++) {
   echo "<tr>"; 
   for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++) {  
       if (isset($result[$i])) {
           echo "<td>".$result[$i]."</td>"; $i++;
       } 
   }
   echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Note the table has no limit on how many columns there are just rows.

> Link to working example http://lakeside.donavonscreativeinnovations.com/

Comment: try printing out the value of $row. What does your echo $result look like? It looks like you are iterating over the array of characters within a SINGLE element from your result set.

Comment: you are echoing $result[$i], which is the i-th letter of $result string (the string is understood as a char array, like in good old C language)

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through the results. Something like this:

```
// $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result); // Count rows if you want to know

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) { // Loop through rows
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $key => $value) { // Loop through columns
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

At the moment you loop through each character of a column.

Comment: Wouldn't that duplicate the columns -- it defaults to `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Comment: Thank you for your help although... you code displays as the following

title 1 | title 1
-----------------
title 2 | title 2
-----------------
title 3 | title 3
-----------------

should be 
title 1 | title 2 | title 3
-----------------
title 4 | title 5 | title 6


how do i fix this?

Comment: I have added `MYSQLI_ASSOC` to make it only get columns once.

Comment: Niels , forgive me for so many questions it looks like they are now displaying the results in a single line vertically . Simple fix?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT title FROM donuts");

echo '<table>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{

  echo '<tr>';

  foreach ($row as $cell)
  {
    echo '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
  }

  echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
echo $result=$row['title'];
```

and then you loop through this with the code:

```
$i=0; for($tr=1;$tr<=$rows;$tr++)
              { echo "<tr>"; 
                    for($td=1;$td<=$cols;$td++)
                       {  
                   if (isset($result[$i])) {
                     **echo "<td>".$result[$i]."</td>"; $i++;**
```

Thus you loop through a string outputting each character in that string.